# Разбирался в особенностях декоратора и столкнулся со странной проблемой

Tags: python, декоратор

Вот мой код:

```
def decor(x):
    def wrap():
        try:
            x()
        except:
            return ('error')
    return wrap
@decor
def f():
    a=5
    return (a)
@decor
def F():
    a=open('251.txt')
    w=a.read()
    return (w)
print(f())
print(F())
```

Вот что он выдает:

```
None
error
```

А хочу я чтобы он выдавал это:

```
5
error
```

Потом переделал код и он сработал как надо:

```
def decor(x):
    def wrap():
        try:
            x()
        except:
            print('error')
    return wrap

@decor
def f():
    a=5
    print(a)

@decor
def F():
    a=open('251.txt')
    w=a.read()
    print(w)

f()
F()
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять в чём ошибка первого кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас выводится `None`, потому что вы пытаетесь вывести на печать результат функции `x()` которая ничего не возвращает.

Если вы хотите, чтобы функция возвращала значение переменной a, то добавьте return перед ее вызовом

```
def decor(x):
    def wrap():
        try:
            return x()
        except:
            return 'error'
    return wrap
@decor
def f():
    a=5
    return (a)
@decor
def F():
    a=open('251.txt')
    w=a.read()
    return (w)
print(f())
print(F())
```

**Результат:**

```
5
error
```

Но вообще тут структура кода полностью неправильная...